# What is the correct syntax for a tuple argument?

Tags: etherscan, bridge

I am trying to interact with a bridge but I am stuck at correctly inputting the argument. The bridge in question is the ETH-RSK (ROOTSTOCK) **Tokenbridge**.
They way the bridge works is, you call the **receivetokensTO** function on Eth mainnet first (bridge contract https://etherscan.io/address/0x12ed69359919fc775bc2674860e8fe2d2b6a7b5d), after 30 minutes 3 federators have to vote the tx you initiated and then you can call the "**claim**" function on the RSK chain (bridge contract on rsk side https://rootstock.blockscout.com/address/0x9d11937E2179dC5270Aa86A3f8143232D6DA0E69) .
All 3 validators/federators have voted for the tx using the **VoteTransaction** function (here is one example https://rootstock.blockscout.com/tx/0xd8b0aec3261bf158893791abccba9b880b63d367c43b866e18cefc2b7cfb19f5 ) and with the arguments in that tx I have to compile a tuple argument in order to use the **claim** function.
Here is an example of a successful transaction using the **claim** function: https://rootstock.blockscout.com/tx/0xa0ff8067834c655b487e085301523297d4251edf0e79f0a8ace2b02625979eb1
If I wanted to replicate that former tx and interact with the contract using blockscout and call the **claim** function using the same arguments `["0xd83eb40979ca0dabe945e22629a72765dc9a39bd","5988000000","0x090c7db40af761ef48a163bca4fb49bc46499e679e833e5d75ab13bcb8632bcb","0x59f0b88d97c3034aa6d59f4934eafa2f92f43b5a1d7a0390c4532d2096785181","295"]`
I get the error **"Error: Address "undefined" is invalid.
Version: viem@1.2.5"**
My first guess is this is a syntax issue, can someone with more experience perhaps help me format this in a way to be able to claim my stuck tx?